# PHP MySql WebService on Linux Apache: HTTP Error: socket read of headers timed out

Tags: php, web-services, apache

Webservice is hosted on Linux server with apache webserver.
i have used Nusoap v1.123.

I am trying to call the webmethods of the webservice through remote client php script using Nusoap.
I am getting HTTP Error: socket read of headers timed out. for certain webmethods.
some webmethods work fine.
All these webmethods does querying/updating the db and takes few seconds to complete.

i dont know which timeout values to set and where.
(whether in Apache conf filee or php.ini file or nusoap).

i tried with different values like
In Apache: timeout: Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 20.
In Php.ini: default_socket_timeout: 300

still no success.

any clues are highly appreciated.

Comment: One more observation, when i try to call a separate php on the server which does db access / update, client browser receives : Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE).

Comment: I tried on localhost with IIS 5.1, all webmethods work fine. What is making it fail on the cloud server?